# What should I use for guest identifier?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, httpclient

I'm opening up a feature on my site that will not require a user to create a profile. I need to create and track user ids so I'm curious what others use as an indentifier for guest accounts.  Here are some of my thoughts:

1. Capture the client IP address and use that
2. Assign a unique ID

Just curious if anyone else has done the same and what they used.

Comment: Behind NAT routers, several users can (and will) have the same IP address. Is there something like a unique Session ID in PHP, too, like it is in ASP.NET?

Comment: @UweKeim, it's not dependant on the language, but on server software.

Comment: Have you already considered using OpenID?

Comment: @UweKeim, yes there are session IDs in PHP but it needs to be persistent.@RobW, I'll take a look at OpenID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cookies. But, anyway, it's exploitable.

Don't use IP, as the IP can change very often. And, in cookies, assing an unique ID, as you marked in your question.

Comment: @Paul, just set cookie's lifetime to something like a year or so.

Answer (score 0):

These days user don`t like to register over and over again. More and more of the data over internet is going to the cloud. Rob W suggests [openid](http://openid.net/) some info about the [openids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) on wikipedia. Why not use facebook, google accaunt. There are other solutions - more or less what you need - [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/), [disqus](http://disqus.com/) these are more "comment oriented".

Comment: I agree, but basically all I need is a unique identifier linked to a guest user so registration isn't required.  It'll be used as an id in my DB table to retrieve data once they return to the site

Answer (score -1):

is regular php session inefficient? you can add to it anything just to complicate the structure, but anyway it'll be always exploitable, so I would keep it as simple as possible - use session ;)